# Is there a way to sum values to the right of a + symbol across many cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am normally well versed in Excel but I am having a blank on this one.

I have a bunch of formulas eg:

```
VLOOKUP($C22, 'Pivot Table'!$A$4:$DD$400, 13, FALSE)+3162
VLOOKUP($C22, 'Pivot Table'!$A$4:$DD$400, 22, FALSE)+18
VLOOKUP($C22, 'Pivot Table'!$A$4:$DD$400, 31, FALSE)
VLOOKUP($C22, 'Pivot Table'!$A$4:$DD$400, 40, FALSE)+8.6
```

and so on

What I need is a formula that will sum all numbers to the right of the +, trying to avoid using VBA (which would be super easy) for reasons beyond my control.

Comment: Is the beginning (before the +) always the same size? And is the text after it only going to be the numbers you're summing?

Comment: Well, I don't have much time right now but this is a quick way of doing it (though it's ugly). It's also incomplete unless each cell has a +# at the end.
=SUM(MID(A1,FIND("+",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("+",A1)),MID(A2,FIND("+",A2)+1,LEN(A2)-FIND("+",A2)),MID(A3,FIND("+",A3)+1,LEN(A3)-FIND("+",A3)),MID(A4,FIND("+",A4)+1,LEN(A4)-FIND("+",A4)))

Comment: I don't think there's any way to extract the text from a formula (without VBA), short of copying each formula and pasting as text. (At which point, you could just be copying and pasting your values directly.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, Jackie the length can be variable. I also just realised that sometimes it could be a minus, I think it will have to be either a manual thing or maybe a UDF, I really wanted to avoid this because I don't want to have to explain the method to a non technical person :(.

Comment: Which excel version? In Excel 2013 you can use FORMULATEXT function to extract the formula as text, you could then extract any number at the end

Comment: Thanks all for your help, I am not on 2013 so can't use your solution Barry but I have flagged it as correct being that it would work if I was on a newer version. Another great formula now added to my black book :). Thanks again all. I ended up summing manually (which I detest) and all sums are now verified back to the base data (which surprise me that I didn't make a single keying error :p  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Excel 2013 you can use `FORMULATEXT` function to get the formula as text, then extract the number, e.g. with formulas in A2 down use this formula in B2 copied down

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(10^9,RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(A2),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})+0),0)`

That will extract numbers from the right of the text (up to 8 digits, excluding sign). It will give you negative, positive or zero if there is no number at the right of the formula.

Clearly you can sum column B for the total

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere as neat as @barry (of course!) but an alternative that works for you examples is to copy the formulae and on the copy Find what `*)`, Replace with: (nothing) and sum the results.